# Merging two columns causes them to skip lines

Tags: paste

I am trying to combine two text files each containing one column of numbers, I am using paste method to achieve this, but when I run my script it doesn't put them together correctly rather it skips a line and puts it in the opposide side. I checked if there are any hidden spaces and I could not see anything like that. Anyone knows how to achieve my goal?

**Script:**

```
grep '<ID>' base_*.dat | sed 's/.*>//' > id
grep '<Name>' base_*.dat | sed 's/.*>//' > name
paste id name > result
```

**Current output:**

```
5
    5
4
    5
4
    -1
5
    5
5
    -1
```

**Intended output:**

```
5    5
4    5
4   -1
5    5
5   -1
```

Comment: Your source file came from Windows?

Comment: Not sure to be honest, just a got data set as a training material containing a lot of .dat files. That need to be processed.

Comment: Run the files through `dos2unix` or if you don't have that use `tr -d $'\r'`